How to fix mixed content error when embedding a FastAPI app as iframe
I'm deploying a web application using NiceGUI (fastAPI) on Google Cloud Run. The main application is served over HTTPS, but I’m embedding a sub-application (Chainlit) as an iframe within the main app. The Chainlit app is mounted as a FastAPI subapp.
When I load the main app (served locally or remotely), I get a mixed content error and the Chainlit endpoint does not load: "Mixed Content: The page at 'https://main-app.a.run.app/' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure frame 'http://main-app.a.run.app/chat/'. This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.
As an observation when I manually change the iframe URL with the browser inspector tool to something else and then put it back again, the iframe loads correctly.
Question: What could be causing the subapp to default to HTTP, and how can I ensure it is always served over HTTPS to avoid the mixed content error?
My implementation:
from nicegui import context, app, ui

import chainlit as cl
from chainlit.utils import mount_chainlit


ui.html(f'<iframe id="chat_frame" src="{CHAINLIT_BASE_URL}" style="width: 100%; height: 100%; border: none;"></iframe>').classes('w-full h-full')

@app.middleware("http")
async def add_security_headers(request, call_next):
    response = await call_next(request)
    
    # Content Security Policy header for iframe embedding
    response.headers['Content-Security-Policy'] = f"frame-ancestors 'self' {URL_REMOTE};"

    return response

mount_chainlit(app=app, target="chainlit_app.py", path="/chat")  # Mount the Chainlit app

ui.run(title=TITLE, favicon=FAVICON, storage_secret=API_KEY,
       host=BASE_URL, port=PORT)


If you are behind a trusted load balancer, you can use proxy_headers=True and forwarded_allow_ips='<ip of load balancer>' to tell uvicorn (which the run method in NiceGUI forwards its calls to)  that it can trust the X-Forwarded-* headers from that specific node.

That did it, the issue seems solved now. Appreciate it,@MatsLindh
